# Best practice for fixing multiple URL's for same product issue in Magento1?

Tags: magento-1, url-rewrite, sitemaps, duplicate, canonical

This Magento1 website has 5 different URL's for each product that are indexing in Google. Examples below:

- www.url.com/category1/product-name.html
- www.url.com/brands/product-name.html
- www.url.com/product-name.html

etc..

Thought process for best way to resolve is truncate the core_url_rewrite table

Then re-index URL's and allow the table to rebuild from scratch?

How then to ensure that the category's, search pages and brand pages all link to the same product URL?

The chosen ideal structure that the canonical will be on is below:

www.url.com/product-name.html

The site has 1 store, and circa 2000 products, and around 300 categories, and 40 brands.

Really looking to create best practice, and order of events to work through to resolve issue. With the last ones being re-generate sitemap, submit new sitemap to Google Webmaster tools.

Comment: If you don't mind me asking. Why do you have 2k products in 3k categories? Wouldn't layered navigation be easier?That said. You can turn off the categories showing in the URL from System->Configuration ->Catalog[Catalog]->SEO-> Use Categories Path for Product URLs. Have you tried that?

Comment: 2000 products and 300 categories, not 3k categories

Comment: We have the correct settings now in place, the question really is correct procedure for cleaning up the url_rewrite table and rebuilding sitemap etc from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Change

   System->Configuration ->Catalog[Catalog]->SEO-> Use Categories Path for Product URLs

   to 'No'
2. Truncate the table 'core_url_rewrites'
3. Rebuild Indexes
4. Clear the Cache

Comment: Thanks. That's what I was planning to do, with some other steps in the midst of that like take a backup of the core_url_rewrite table. My worry is with the volume of products that the reindex of URL's may time out and not complete, but I guess server settings can be changed to allow a longer time limit.

Comment: One of my stores has more than 50k products. Its testing server is on a slow VPS and never timed out the indexing

Comment: ok, thanks for the feedback, I've had occasions on Magento1 where it times out, but from memory, that was for over 100k of products now I think about it, so all should be fine, cheers for comments.